# expandable div in master page

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a web application in Asp.Net. I've created my master page and inside I have a div.In page1 for example I have another div that is positioned on the div from the master page.I want to make my div from the master page expandable if my div from page 1 expands.Now is just fixed and if my div from page1 is increasing it's going over the div from the master page.

I tried to set the div's master page height like this:

```
 min-height:548px;
         height:auto;
         height:548px;
```

But it didn't helped me.How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show the rendered html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the div on the `window` `resize` `event`

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

   var someHeight = window.innerHeight; // compute the desired height
   document.getElementById('myDiv').style.height = someHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `height:548px;`. Once an explicit height is set, the height of the div will not change.